# How to add a new configuration using Gradle Script Kotlin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

In groovy, it's done like this...

```
// build.gradle
apply 'java'
configurations {

   //adding a configuration
   myConfiguration
}
```

But how is it done in [Gradle Script Kotlin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin)?

```
// build.gradle.kts
apply {
    plugin("java")
}

// What to do here??
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can do this by calling `create` on `configurations` object:

```
configurations.create("myConfiguration")
```

To validate that configuration actually created you can add this line to your gradle-kotlin-script:

```
configurations.forEach { println(it.name) }
// myConfiguration
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried something like:

```
apply<JavaPlugin>()
apply<JavaPluginConvention> {
  setSourceCompatibility(1.8)
}
```

Hopefully, it helps